# Is the '$' (end of line anchor) somehow concurrent with the '\n' (newline)? Please explain these results

Tags: regular-expressions, newlines

In normal regex, I would expect the following to be true:

```lisp
(should (equal (string-match "^abc$\nx" "abc\nx ") 0))    ;; nope! nil
(should (equal (string-match "^abc\n$x" "abc\nx ") nil))
(should (equal (string-match "^abc\nx " "abc\nx ") 0))
```

However, the first one fails. Can someone please explain to me why this is the case? The only way I can make sense of it is that somehow the '$' is considered "on top of" the '\n', but that is very strange and I don't see it documented anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

`$` is matched only when it's used at the end of the regexp, or at the boundary of a grouping or alternative construct.

See `(info "(elisp) Regexp Special")` or [Regexp-Special](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Special.html) for more information.

Comment: Not entirely true. Both, the following forms return 0: `(string-match "^abc\\($\\)\nx" "abc\nx ")` and `(string-match "^abc\\($\\|y\\)\nx" "abc\nx ")`

Please ensure completeness when citing the manual. (Emacs 28.1).

Comment: If I'm putting in a reference to the emacs manual, I don't see why I should copy exactly what it says. That's why the manual exists, after all :-)

Comment: Thanks, this mostly clarifies why it does not work then: the manual says it is for historical compatibility. But then I would agree that it's either a bug that I am successfully using it to match not at the end of the string in some cases, or the documentation is incorrect in saying that it cannot be used. Rather it should probably say the behavior is undefined when not at the end of a string, if this is intended.

Comment: @rpluim The problem is that the statement becomes simply false and misleading by omitting the special cases. For an instance it is possible to match the empty string at the line end in the middle of the regexp just by grouping: `\($\)`.

Comment: People who need to use the special cases should definitely read the manual, but whatever, I edited the answer.